# PHP MySQL image hit counter

Tags: php, mysql, image, hitcounter

I'm new to PHP and have been working on a hit counter. The hit counter works great but now I want to convert the numbers into images.

I have created 12 images 0-9, a spacer, and a comma image.

I have searched high and low for a hint of what I need to do to convert the number format into images and have had no success. So far all I have found is how to make a basic hit counter using files only, PHP/MySQL, and how to display an encrypted image using PHP/MySQL.

**So the question is:**
How do I tell the given code to show images in place of each number?

*Example of current PHP result: **Hit: 2,435***

I want my PHP to get the total number of hits *(example)* and then take and replace the 2,435 with the following code:

```
<img src="img/2.png"><img src="img/comma.png"><img src="img/4.png"><img src="img/3.png"><img src="img/5.png">
```

---

**Note: I use lots of notes in the code I show here. This way any new coders can more easily understand the scripts being displayed. I will add my final/completed code at the bottom of this post so everyone can see the final product when I have found a solution.**

---

*This code is fully fictional as a text hit counter*

```
// Begin open SQL connection to database
$concount = mysqli_connect("site","username","password","database");
// End connection to database

// Begin update number of hits
mysqli_query($concount,"UPDATE counter SET hits = hits + 1");
// End update number of hits

// Begin get number of hits
$hits = ("SELECT SUM(hits) FROM counter");
// End get number of hits

// Begin show number of hits
$result = mysqli_query($concount,$hits);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "Hits:&nbsp;" . number_format((float)$row['0']) . "&nbsp;";
}
// End show number of hits

// Begin close SQL connection
mysqli_close($con);
// End close SQL connection
```

---

**Edit: Below is the final result of my code.
Note that the array in this script puts a ' at the beginning and end of the image array. (See following example)**

```
Array ( [0] => ' [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => ' )
```

**So unless I wanted a broken image on ether end of my hit counter I had to utilize them. I renamed my transparent image that I had already planed on using on both ends to '.png (See following example)**

```
<img src="img/'.png"><img src="img/2.png"><img src="img/4.png"><img src="img/3.png"><img src="img/5.png"><img src="img/'.png">
```

---

**Final Code**
*This code is fully fictional as a image hit counter*

```
// Begin open SQL connection to database
$concount = mysqli_connect("site","username","password","database");
// End connection to database

// Begin update number of hits
mysqli_query($concount,"UPDATE counter SET hits = hits + 1");
// End update number of hits

// Begin get number of hits
$hits = ("SELECT SUM(hits) FROM counter");
// End get number of hits

// Begin assign $hits an id
$result = mysqli_query($concount,$hits);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$totalhits=("'" . $row[0] . "'");
}
// End assign $hits an id

// Begin get id for number of hits, split the string into array, and assign id to numbers
$arr = str_split($totalhits);
$numbers = $arr;
foreach ($numbers as $value) {
// End get id for number of hits, split the string into array, and assign id to numbers

// Begin show number of hits as images
    echo "<img src=\"img/".$value.".png\">";
} 
// End show number of hits as images

// Begin close SQL connection
mysqli_close($con);
// End close SQL connection
```

---

**Final Notes:
I have not tried adding a comma to larger numbers or removing the apostrophe on the array yet. If I do I'll come back and edit this.**

Comment: Normally its not wise to use images for number. You should use numbers in html with cool CSS.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com
I agree that using images for number or any text etc is not good but that CSS is better. Because I don't know how to have a font installed on some ones smart phone or because some one might have downloads of that sort blocked I have chosen to use images. Everything is set to a specific size as well to prevent distortion etc.

Comment: So in short you cant use customized font in your whole website ? cool !

Comment: OP , Care to check the answer ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I'm new to PHP. I'm still trying to get a result. I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: OP cant you tell here that you didnt get answer ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Actually because of the answers. I have been able to get half of my code working. I'm still working on it. Also the <hr> tags in my post where correct they are not part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the hit counter into array with each value containing single digit, and then use for loop to append images.

```
<?php
$array = str_split($your_hit_variable_from_mysql);
if(!empty($array)){
  foreach($array as $single){
        echo '<img src="'.$single.'.jpg"'>;
  }
}else{
        echo '<img src="0.jpg"'>;
}
?>
```

**Ensure** you are storing number in integer format , not string like 52,200 with comma.

For more check **[Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868896/how-do-i-explode-an-integer)**

**EDIT:** Added exception handling when there is counter 0 for image.

Comment: The answers that both jQuery.PHP.Magento.com and @bvdb provided helped direct me to my final answer. Thank you. I selected jQuery's answer because he answered my question and didn't provide me with info I didn't ask for. I still appreciate the reply from bvdb.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use `str_split($str)` to convert a string to an array of characters.
Next you can iterate them with a simple `for` or `foreach` loop.**

**EDIT:**

There are several options on **how to visualize the images**.
You could just take html `<img src=''>` tags or CSS.

**If you use CSS**, then you can create 1 image which contains all individual images (i.e. a spritemap or tilemap). Then use CSS to split it up again in single images. You can accomplish this by defining a general declaration for the background image, and then let each numeric value define an offset inside that image.

```
.nr1 .nr2 .nr3 {    
  background: url(sprites.png) no-repeat;
}
.nr1 { background-position: 0 0 ; }
.nr2 { background-position: 0 -21px ; }
.nr3 { background-position: -21px -42px ; }
```

The task of finding the exact offset may seem time-consuming. But there are several **free online tools** that can do this for you. I personally used [this one](http://wearekiss.com/spritepad) a lot. You can just drag the individual images to your webbrowser, and it will create a single image and the necessary CSS.

One of the advantages of using a spritemap, is that **all images are loaded together**. If you use individual images you can see some kind of flickering while the images are loading.